# Decided to study Mathematics at the age of 50

Tags: education

I finally decided to pursue a math degree. I need to point out that I am 50 years old with a Telecommmunications Enginnering Degree, and have always loved Mathematics. I am looking to connect with someone with a similar situation to share my experience with him etc....also any advice is welcome

Comment: Hi Sami. It's great that you've decided to pursue learning mathematics, but this website is not suitable for personal advice or finding connections -- it is for _mathematics_. You could look at more community-focused forums on the same subject, e.g. you could try reddit.com/r/math.